# How can I export Python multidimensional numpy array to different files based on second value of each line?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to export a numpy array to different csv files using a function and based on 
the second value of each line of data array. My goal is to export data to the same file if the second value of each line is equal. So far I can create diffferent files but I also export all data to each file. The second part of the problem is that I don't have a maximum number of options for second values in my array. This is the code that I've done:

```
a = np.array([(2,"Ana",9),(5,"Maria",4),(6,"Joao",3),
     (1,"Ana",4)])

export_path = r"c:"

def export(array_values):
    names = []
    for i in xrange(len(array_values)):
        names.append(array_values[i][1])
    names = sorted(set(names))

    for i in xrange(len(array_values)):
        for j in xrange(len(names)):
            if array_values[i][1] == names[j]:
                name = "..."
                export_file_path = os.path.join(export_path,name + ".csv")
                myfile = open(export_file_path, 'wb')
                wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
                wr.writerows(array_values)

export(a)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Ivo

Comment: I'd like to get a better picture of your end result. In the example array, `a` that you have given, is it true that you would like to have 3 files:
Ana.csv,Maria.csv, and Joao.csv
? 
Ana.csv would have the contents of a[0], a newline, and a[3]

Maria.csv would have the contents a[1]

and 
Joao.csv would have the contents a[2]



Correct ?

Comment: Exacly what I had in mind. The final result would be:

Ana.csv 
Data:
2,"Ana",9
1,"Ana",4

Maria.csv
Data:
5,"Maria",4

Joao.Csv
Data:
6,"Joao",3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

itertools.groupby() makes this easy.

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter
import csv

a = np.array([(2,"Ana",9),(5,"Maria",4),(6,"Joao",3), (1,"Ana",4)])
name = itemgetter(1)
a = sorted(a, key = name)
for k, g in it.groupby(a, name):
    filename = k + '.csv' 
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(list(g))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. That was exactly what I was looking for, and you did it with a very clean and readable code. Kind Regards. Ivo

Answer (score 1):

Alright:

```
def export(A):
    _v2=set(A[:,1])
    for item in _v2:
        sub_A=A[A[:,1]==item][:,[0,2]]
        with open(item+'.txt', 'w') as f:
            wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            wr.writerows(sub_A)
```

should generate 3 files: i.e., `ana.txt` (since the name already becomes the file name, we can drop it from the final csv file):

```
2,9
1,4
```

Comment: I would also like to thank you since your code is also solving my problem. Kind Regards. Ivo

Answer (score 1):

First, figure out how many files you will need:

```
>>> unq, unq_idx = np.unique(a[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
>>> unq
array(['Ana', 'Joao', 'Maria'], 
      dtype='|S5')
>>> unq_idx
array([0, 2, 1, 0])
```

You can now loop over the groups, extract the corresponding rows, and save them:

```
for j, name in enumerate(unq):
    sub_a = a[unq_idx == j]
    # sub_a holds the lines that have name in the 2nd column
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of pointers that might be useful ...

Sort the initial array:

```
In [53]: a1 = sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[1])

In [54]: a1
Out[54]:
[array(['2', 'Ana', '9'],
      dtype='|S5'),
 array(['1', 'Ana', '4'],
      dtype='|S5'),
 array(['6', 'Joao', '3'],
      dtype='|S5'),
 array(['5', 'Maria', '4'],
      dtype='|S5')]
```

Next, you can filter out values which have the second item same like so:

```
In [55]: filter(lambda x: x[1] ==  a1[0][1] , a1)
Out[55]:
[array(['2', 'Ana', '9'],
      dtype='|S5'),
 array(['1', 'Ana', '4'],
      dtype='|S5')]
```

Save these values in a file with name a1[0][1]

Filter out the rest of the values (name this new list a1, which is not shown below):

```
In [56]: filter(lambda x: x[1] !=  a1[0][1] , a1)
Out[56]:
[array(['6', 'Joao', '3'],
      dtype='|S5'),
 array(['5', 'Maria', '4'],
      dtype='|S5')]
```

Repeat until you find an empty list. You can either do a recursion or a nurmal loop. Anything is fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, in your code, you use the  `'wb'` option in `open()`. This will cause things to be overwritten. Havent been able to follow your code very well because the indentation on my browser isnt working in the code segment ...

Comment: The other method is to use what you have already used ...
`names = a.T[1]`, and then do a for loop like so:
`for name in names:
    val = filter(lambda x: x[1] == name, a)
    # save val in filename name+'.csv'`

And you are done